# INNER JOIN change SUM result

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE beauty.customer_payments
(
customer_id integer,
date date,
amount numeric(10,2),
CONSTRAINT customer_payments_customer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY    (customer_id)
    REFERENCES beauty.customers (customer_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE beauty.sales
(
product_id integer,
customer_id integer,
sell_date date NOT NULL,
qty integer NOT NULL,
sell_price numeric(10,2) NOT NULL,
expiry_date date NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT sales_customer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
    REFERENCES beauty.customers (customer_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT sales_product_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES beauty.products (product_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Balance of payments `beauty.customer_payments` for customer_id=6 is 0

```
 SELECT * FROM beauty.customer_payments 
 WHERE customer_id=6;
```

| customer_id | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2020-11-14 | 75.00 |
| 6 | 2020-11-14 | -75.00 |

```
 SELECT * FROM beauty.sales 
 WHERE customer_id=6;
```

| product_id | customer_id | sell_date | qty | sell_price | expiry_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76 | 6 | 2020-11-14 | 1 | 75.00 | 2022-03-03 |
| 83 | 6 | 2020-11-14 | 1 | 10.00 | 2022-06-23 |
| 85 | 6 | 2020-11-14 | 1 | 10.00 | 2022-06-23 |
| 44 | 6 | 2020-11-14 | 1 | 12.00 | 2022-06-23 |
| 41 | 6 | 2020-11-14 | 1 | 15.00 | 2022-03-26 |
| 96 | 6 | 2020-11-14 | 1 | 75.00 | 2022-03-15 |
| 28 | 6 | 2020-11-14 | 1 | 4.00 | 2022-01-22 |
| 33 | 6 | 2020-11-14 | 1 | 4.00 | 2023-01-23 |
| 37 | 6 | 2020-11-14 | 1 | 4.00 | 2023-01-23 |
| 40 | 6 | 2020-11-14 | 1 | 4.00 | 2023-08-13 |

(10 rows)

```
SELECT customer_id, SUM(qty * sell_price) AS purchased
FROM beauty.sales
WHERE customer_id=6
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

| customer_id | purchased |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 213.00 |

```
SELECT s.customer_id, 
SUM(qty * sell_price) AS purchased, 
SUM(cp.amount) AS paid,
SUM(qty * sell_price - cp.amount) AS balance
FROM beauty.sales s
INNER JOIN beauty.customer_payments cp 
ON cp.customer_id = s.customer_id
WHERE s.customer_id=6 
GROUP BY s.customer_id;
```

| customer_id | purchased | paid | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1065.00 | 0.00 | 1065.00 |

Please advise WHY after adding `JOIN (INNER, LEFT, RIGHT)` calculation goes wrong and how to solve this multi-calculation issue?
As I see similar question all of them based on not cross-tables calculations like `SUM(qty * sell_price - cp.amount)`

Delete payments

`

```
DELETE FROM beauty.customer_payments
WHERE customer_id=6;`
```

Add new ZERO payment

```
INSERT INTO beauty.customer_payments(
customer_id, date, amount)
VALUES (6, '2020-11-17', 0);
```

| customer_id | purchased | paid | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 213.00 | 0.00 | 213.00 |

Add payment 10

```
INSERT INTO beauty.customer_payments(
customer_id, date, amount)
VALUES (6, '2020-11-17', 10);

SELECT * FROM beauty.customer_payments WHERE customer_id=6;
```

| customer_id | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2020-11-17 | 0.00 |
| 6 | 2020-11-17 | 10.00 |

```
SELECT s.customer_id, 
.......
INNER JOIN beauty.customer_payments cp 
.......
```

| customer_id | purchased | paid | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 426.00 | 100.00 | 326.00 |

Correct payment with negative amount

```
INSERT INTO beauty.customer_payments(
customer_id, date, amount)
VALUES (6, '2020-11-17', -10);
```

```
SELECT * FROM beauty.customer_payments WHERE customer_id=6;
```

| customer_id | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2020-11-17 | 0.00 |
| 6 | 2020-11-17 | 10.00 |
| 6 | 2020-11-17 | -10.00 |

```
SELECT s.customer_id, 
.......
INNER JOIN beauty.customer_payments cp 
.......
```

| customer_id | purchased | paid | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 639.00 | 0.00 | 639.00 |

What is this `INNER JOIN' calculate?

Comment: There are "No records into beauty.customer_payments" but that `inner join` query returns that record? That doesn't seem possible.

Comment: pls see changes... means NO RECORDS for `customer_id=6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you probably wouldn't want to match each payment to each sale (unless there's an additional identifier matching specific payments to specific sales, not just matching each to a customer).

If a customer has 2 sales for $10 and $15, and two payments for $9 and $14, your join is going to match each payment to each sale for that customer, creating something like

| Sale | Payment |
| --- | --- |
| $10 | $9 |
| $10 | $14 |
| $15 | $9 |
| $15 | $14 |

So the sum of the sales after the join will be $50, not $25 (as you might be expecting). I think the above answers your question about why the join doesn't do what you expect.

The exact query you want might be a little different (do you want all customers even if they have no sales? is it possible for customers to have payments if they don't have a sale?), but in general I'd expect something like the following to work. There are multiple ways of doing this, but I think the following is easy to understand since it aggregates the data into one payment row per customer and one sales row per customer before joining them.

```
SELECT
 s.customer_id,
 s.purchased,
 cp.amount as paid,
 s.purchased - cp.amount as balance
FROM
 (SELECT s.customer_id, 
 SUM(s.qty * s.sell_price) AS purchased
 FROM beauty.sales s 
 GROUP BY s.customer_id) s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT cp.customer_id, 
 SUM(cp.amount) AS amount
 FROM beauty.customer_payments cp 
 GROUP BY cp.customer_id) cp
ON s.customer_id = cp.customer_id
WHERE s.customer_id = 6
```

Comment: Thank a lot for this detailed explanation why it's calculate different  with different entries of sales and payments and for the code. I works nice.